# Get User Profile in Keycloak using REST Api

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect

I have got a accessToken by calling the keycloak endpoint `/token` using REST Api as follows

```bash
curl -d 'client_id=myclient' -d 'username=username' -d 'password=password' -d 'grant_type=password' -d 'scope=openid' -d 'client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' 'http://192.168.43.29:8080/realms/aurcc/protocol/openid-connect/token'
```

But by using this api, when a request is made to the `/userinfo` endpoint, response will only contains sub,given_name,preferred_name,email_verified,family_name. But the response doesn't contain any information about the groups in which the user is added.

Next time, I used keycloak-js adapter in my Vuejs application. There the `/userinfo` endpoint results in a response which contains the above said attributes plus the `groups` attribute. I don't why this weird thing happening.

Help me to get the `groups` attribute in the response of `/userinfo` endpoint.

Comment: In the access token did not include groups information. so `/userinfo` did not include groups information. Only `GET /{realm}/users/{user-id}/groups` can get the user's group information.  And can you shows `keycloak-js` adapter include groups information? I think that is not correct information.

Comment: I solved the problem by adding `groups` mapper in the clients scope section. Anyway thanks for your answer.